# How to override a standard link in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i have to override a standard link in Home Page layout .My screenshot of Home page layout is

[image: Screen Shot]

i want to open my visualforce page when user click on link on left bottom Approve/Reject link.How to override its functionality please guideline.is this possible or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to override the existing link? You can add fields to the Approval page layout which gets displayed when the approver will click on Approve/Reject button, but you cannot override it.
You will need to create your own approval process if you absolutely need to show visualforce page on the link.